# How do I add in a text file using python?

Tags: python, discord.py

basically Im making a currency system for my discord bot, and Im trying to figure out how to add a number in the text file, like if I do ^work (which is the prefix + message) it would add +100 to that text file, heres my code by the way also username = message.author.name

```
if (str(username)) in f.read():
      with open("currency.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
      with open("currency.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in lines:
          if line.strip("\n") != (str(username)):
            (+100)
    else:
      f = open ("currency.txt","a")
      f.write (str(username)+("+100"))
      f.write ("\n")
      f.close()
```

Comment: Where's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a json file (you can create a global variable so you can use it anywhere), so you should use `@client.event` which makes it fire up when the bot goes online.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global currency #Creates the global variable
    try:
        with open('currency.json') as f: #Opens json file
            currency = json.load(f)
```

To save the json file you have to create a definition with a `_` so it can be called anywhere.

```
def _save():
    with open('currency.json', 'w+') as f: #Opens the file
        json.dump(currency, f) #Dumps the json file
```

If you want to store numbers in it, it must be a string, a command to do so would look like this:

```
@client.command()
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id) #Defines the author ID (Always a string!)

    if id not in currency: #Checks if the ID is already on the json file
        currency[id] = 500 #Sets the currency
        _save() #Saves the json file

    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account :x:")
```

So the final code would look something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global currency #Creates the global variable
    try:
        with open('currency.json') as f: #Opens json file
            currency = json.load(f)

@client.command()
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id) #Defines the author ID (Always a string!)

    if id not in currency: #Checks if the ID is already on the json file
        currency[id] = 500 #Sets the currency
        _save() #Saves the json file

    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account :x:")

def _save():
    with open('currency.json', 'w+') as f: #Opens the file
        json.dump(currency, f) #Dumps the json file
```

PD: The file `currency.json` should have this in it:

```
{}
```

Comment: to add, shouldn't we open in append mode...?

Comment: We are not using a list so no, we should not use .append() as its not necessary

Comment: Also, we are using the user ID, as the user name could change.